How to generate an iFrame on a flutter mobile app
I'm working on a podcast app built with flutter and wanted to generate an iframe for specific categories of episodes on the app and add the iframe to an external site in that, what's showing on the app should reflect as well on the external site where the iframe will be added. How can this be achieved?
Quite new to this. Need some assistance.

You can use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview and inject iframe to webview
InAppWebView(
                      initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
                        url: Uri.parse(''),
                      ),
                      initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                        crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                          incognito: GetPlatform.isIOS ? true : false,
                          preferredContentMode: UserPreferredContentMode.MOBILE,
                          verticalScrollBarEnabled: false,
                          horizontalScrollBarEnabled: false,
                        ),
                        android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(clearSessionCache: true, useHybridComposition: true),
                      ),
                      onLoadStop: (controller, url) async {
                        String payload = """
                        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
                        iframe.src = 'https://programiz.pro';
                        iframe.width = '100%';
                        iframe.height = '200px';
                        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
                        """;
                        await controller.evaluateJavascript(source: payload);
                      },
                    ),

